# Android shortcut to write multiple lines of code

Tags: android, xml, performance, android-studio, android-shortcut

I am writing an string array in the string.xml file in android, it is of 300 elements which has incrementing values, just like the one mentioned below with 5 elements :

```
<string-array name="values">
        <item>Item 1</item>
        <item>Item 2</item>
        <item>Item 3</item>
        <item>Item 4</item>
        <item>Item 5</item>
        <item>Item 6</item>
 </string-array>
```

Is there any shortcut to write this code in the xml file?

Comment: write for loop and print value in next line.. and copy them in xml...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [emmet](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) plugin for android studio, it is very helpful when you have to write long serialized xml code, plus  it saves a huge time.

Comment: Thank you @paavan, Just this simple line did the magic : 


string-array[name="values"]>item{$}*300   and expand key after that